# Home/Top Questions list has inconsistent eye icons added to "Watched" tags label

Tags: bug, user-interface

Currently the new "Watched" tag label on the question list only has an eye symbol next to it on the last question in the list. This does not seem intentional as it doesn't make a lot of sense from a UI perspective. Either the eye should be present on all of them, or none of them.

[image: Screenshot of questions with a "Watched" tag label]

Issue reproducible in Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, and Microsoft Edge.

Comment: Reported on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375509

Comment: in my opinion that whole colored "watched" label is an annoying distraction, I don't understand why it was added. at the same time the number of answers is unnecessarily small. the "all questions" view still has a proper display - wouldn't it suffice to add a (non-colored) eye icon somewhere instead of the attention-stealing badge...?

Comment: I agree, makes it eyes go a lot there